# How to display image and .txt file value in a modal popup?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need to create/customize a modal pop up in PHP or Javascript. And I got these requirements:

1. Format the modal in to two columns.
2. Display image from a directory/folder in left column.
3. Display text value (USUALLY PARAGRAPH/SENTENCES) from `.txt` file (in the same directory/folder as the `.jpg` file) in the right column.
4. The right column should have scroll bar automatically when the text is too long.
   note: Not to use MySQL or database things.

i have a code that checks if two files (.jpg and .txt) exist in a folder in cPanel after image click event (*this part works*). then it needs to display the value of the .txt file and the .jpg file in a modal pop up. my code below doesn't call echo the JS function for modal. but shows an alert box instead. the alert doesn't have the image but displays the codes for overlay () instead.

index.php

```
<div class="popup_anchor">
       <div class="Thumb popup_element shadow clearfix" id="u2413"><!-- group -->
        <img class="grpelem" id="u2471" alt="This Week's Events" src="images/blank.gif" onclick="readexisting()"/><!-- state-based BG images -->
       </div>
      </div>

<script>
      function readexisting() {
           jQuery.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: 'controller.php',
              data: {action: 'readexisting', arguments: 'your data'}, 
              success:function(data) {
                                   data = data.split("~:~");
                                   alert(data[0]); // message
                                   //alert(data[1]); // content
              }
          });
      }
```

controller.php

```
<?php
    include_once("execute.php");

    $obj = new Model();

    switch($_POST["action"]){ 
        case 'readexisting': 
            $obj->readexisting();
        break;      
    } 
?>
```

execute.php

```
    <head>
    <style type="text/CSS">
     #overlay {
     display: block;
     position: absolute;
     left: 0px;
     top: 0px;
     width:100%;
     height:100%;
     text-align:center;
     z-index: 1500;
     visibility:hidden;
        }
    #overlay div {
     width:800px;
     margin: 100px auto;
     background-color: none;/*rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9)*/
     border:none;
     padding:15px;
     text-align:center;
    }
    </style>


    <script type="text/javascript">
    function overlay() {
        el = document.getElementById("overlay");
        el.style.visibility = (el.style.visibility == "visible") ? "hidden" : "visible";
}
 </script>   
 </head>
 <body>

 <div id="overlay">
     <div>
          <img src="events/event-01.jpg" alt="module" style="width:230px; height:313px;">
          <p><a href='#close' onclick='overlay()'><img src="images/close_btn.png" alt="module" style="width:15px; height:15px; position:relative; margin-left: 380px; top: -317px;"></a></p>
     </div>

   </body>
</html>
        <?php
        class Model {


           public function readexisting() {
               if (file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/Proj/events/folder-01/event-01.txt") && file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/Proj/events/folder-01/event-01.jpg")) {  
                    echo "<script>";
                     echo "overlay();";
                     echo "</script>";
                    $myFile = ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/Proj/events/folder-01/event-01.txt");
                    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
                    $theData = fread($fh, filesize($myFile));
                    fclose($fh);
                    echo $theData;                       
               } 
               else {
                    echo "The file $myFile does not exist";
               }
           }

        }
        ?>
```

i hope you can help me with this. i've been working on it for 3 days. please feel free to edit my code. thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi Surya still there?

Comment: Ya sorry, I was little caught up. What is the update?

Answer (score 0):

**Place the Overlay div in your index.php itself**

`<div id='overlay'></div>`

And add this CSS code in your index.php

```
#overlay{
display: none;
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
width:100%;
height:100%;
text-align:center;
z-index: 1500;
}

#overlay div{
width: 50%;
float: left;
overflow: auto;
}
```

**Now call the AJAX function**

```
jQuery('.grpelem').click(function(e)
{
jQuery.ajax(
{
type: "POST",
url: 'controller.php',
data: {action: 'readexisting', arguments: 'your data'}, 
success:function(data)
{
jQuery('#overlay').html('data'); // Output of the controller.php is placed in the overlay DIV
jQuery('#overlay').show('fast'); // Show the Overlay DIV
close_handler();
}
});
});

function close_handler()
{
jQuery('#popup-close').click(function(e)
{
jQuery('#overlay').hide('fast'); // When the close button is clicked it will close the pop up
});
}
```

**In your controller.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['action']))
{
if($_POST['action']=="readexisting")
{
echo "<div><img src='events/event-01.jpg' alt='module' style='width:230px; height:313px;'></div>";
if(file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/Proj/events/folder-01/event-01.txt"))
{
$text_content=file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/Proj/events/folder-01/event-01.txt");
echo "<div>$text_content</div>";
}
echo "<div id='popup-close'>Close</div>";
}
}
```

Comment: Surya S - thanks! i will try your suggestion. but how can i directly place the texts in the right column after getting its value from the .txt file?

Comment: still there my friend? hope you would still want to help me. thanks